# Keras: Load dataset and autocrop relevant area of image

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm working on signature verification and there were a bunch of things I wanted to do using Keras/ OpenCV/ PIL but couldn't find relevant information. I have loaded the dataset folder using `Keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` and now need to:

- Crop the signature from the image stored in the dataset. There may be rectangular borders (or a side of the border) and the border pixels aren't the same in all images.
- Resize the image and also take care of augmentation in the signature.

Example Images:

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

Since I'm working in Keras, I thought of working with its functions but couldn't find any. How can I auto crop/ extract a signature in the dataset I've loaded? About image augmentation, should I do this in this image preprocessing stage, or implement this in CNN model I am using? I am new to image processing and Keras.

Also, because of loading entire training folder as a dataset, the labels are "Genuine" and "Forged". However, there are multiple genuine and forged signatures of a person, and there are multiple people. How do I divide the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organize your directories as follows

````
main_dir
-train_dir
``person1_fake_dir
```person1 fake image
```person1 fake image
---etc
``person1_real_dir
---person1 real image
---person1 real image
--- etc
--person2_fake_dir
--- person2 fake image
--- person2 fake image
--- etc
--person2_real_dir
---person2 real image
---person2 real image
---etc
.
.
.
--personN_fake_dir
---personN fake image
---personN fake image
---etc
--personN_real_dir
---personN real image
---personN real image
--- etc

-test_dir
same structure as train_dir but put test images here

-valid_dir
same structure as train_dir but put validation images here
````

If you have N persons then you will have 2 X N classes

You can then use tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory()
to input your data. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) You don't have to worry about cropping the images just set the image size in flow to something like (256,256).
Code below show the rest of the code you need

```
data_gen=tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(resize=1/255)
train_gen=data_gen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(224,224), color-mode='grayscale')
valid_gen=data_gen.flow_from_directory(valid_dir, target_size=(224,224), color-mode='grayscale', shuffle=False)
test_gen=data_gen.flow_from_directory(test_dir, target_size=(224,224), color-mode='grayscale', shuffle=False)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics='accuracy')
history=model.fit(train_gen, epochs=20, verbose=1)
accuracy=model.evaluate (test_gen)[1]*100
print ('Model accuracy is ', accuracy)
```

Note your  model will not be able to tell fake from real in the general case. It should work for persons 1 through N. You could try putting all the fake images in one class directory and all the real images in another class directory and train it but I suspect it will not work well in telling real from fake for the general case.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! It solved most of my queries. To enable it to find fake signature from real ones, I will give a few real signatures  and a fake signature of another person as an input